# How to run a python script in the background django

Tags: python, django, background-process

I have a python script (ml.py)that generates some data. I want it to run it in the background daily at 1 AM. How to achieve that ?

ml.py

Takes input from the django models, runs some logic and save the results to the database

I tried installing django-background-tasks and created the following files
tasks.py

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=1)
def hello():
    execute('./scripts/ml.py')

hello(repeat=Task.Daily)
```

In the shell, I executed the following command:

```
python manage.py process_tasks
```

Now I get an error saying that the name execute is not defined

My other questions are :

- Do I have to write the command  python manage.py process_tasks
  everyday ?
- Can I exit out of the command window and does the process
  still run everyday ?

Comment: did you try celery instead?

Comment: I read in this article that celery doesn't support windows anymor. https://medium.com/@robinttt333/running-background-tasks-in-django-f4c1d3f6f06e

Comment: If it can run independently of your Flask app, why not just run it via cron (on Mac/Linux) or Windows Schedule service (on Windows)?

Comment: Why is this dependent of your django project?

Comment: the script takes inputs from the database ( django models) , runs some logic and stores the values in the database ( another django model)